# C++ как вернуть массив типа char из функции

Tags: c++, массивы

Не могу разобраться с возвратом массива из функции. Код:

loadData.cpp

```
#include "SaveText.h"

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

char* SaveText::loadData(char point[]) {
  std::ifstream load;

  load.open(point ios::out | ios::app);

  if(!load) {
    std::cout<<"ERROR!"<<std::endl;    
  }

  char* out_file = new char[200];
  while(1) {
    load.getline(out_file, sizeof(out_file));
    if(load.eof()) break;
  }

  return out_file;//не могу вернуть массив
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "SaveText.h"

int main() {
  char *text_in_file[200];  

  SaveText data; 
  text_in_file = data.loadData("C://Users//...");
  data.saveData(text_in_file, "C://Users//...");

  return 0; 
}
```

По замыслу эта функция будет открывать файл и считывать от туда данные, после эти данные функция вернёт, а потом я буду решать что с ними делать.

Но при компиляции мне выдаёт ошибку:

```
main.cpp:8:16: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'char*' to 'char* [200]'
   text_in_file = data.loadData("C://Users//SilentiumNoxe//Documents//Projects//noteCoin//data//savedata.txt");
                ^
main.cpp:9:107: error: no matching function for call to 'SaveText::saveData(char* [200], const char [75])'
   data.saveData(text_in_file, "C://Users//SilentiumNoxe//Documents//Projects//noteCoin//data//outfile.txt");
                                                                                                           ^
```

Как правильно вернуть в данной ситуации массив и что значит "Нет подходящей функции для вызова"?

P.S. string, vector и пр. не предлагать. Спасибо.

Comment: В строке `text_in_file = data.loadData("C://Users//...");` вы пытаетесь присвоить указатель на `char` *массиву* указателей на `char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот это -

```
char *text_in_file[200];
```

массив из 200 указателей на `char`, причем сама переменная `text_in_file` не может получить никакое иное значение, кроме определенного выше.

Вы же пытаетесь присвоить ей другой указатель, но не просто другой, а указатель на массив `char`.

В лучшем случае можно сделать

```
text_in_file[0] = data.loadData(...);
```

но это явно не то, что вы хотите...

Можно объявить так:

```
char *text_in_file;
```

и тогда ваше присваивание будет логично и понятно :)
Только не забудьте потом вызвать

```
delete[] text_in_file;
```

Comment: Добавлю, что в строке `load.getline(out_file, sizeof(out_file));` ошибка - `sizeof()` вернет размер указателя

Comment: @int3 Спасибо за дополнение!

Comment: @int3 большое спасибо сейчас как раз с этим мучаюсь